# Are there Easter eggs in the opening credits of the remastered original series?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

Specifically, in the first shot of the star field that has the Enterprise, there is a very dense cluster of stars near the center of the screen that, when viewed at a certain speed, seem to look like some kind of slowly rotating wire-frame object. Now maybe I've just stayed up too late, and my eyes are playing tricks, but it seems to be arranged possibly in the shape of the Enterprise itself.. or maybe it's something else?

Does anyone else see that, or know what it is?

**EDIT:** Using DVK's graphic (thanks, DVK), here's the orientation I think I see ..

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  If you can find a still, or better, video, of it, I'd love to see it.

Comment: @Kevin - yeah, I paused it on my DVR, but it's one of those visual things where you can't see it except when the member points are moving relative to the non-member points. The overall field translates left, but there's also a bit of rotation to it as the Enterprise appears from the left edge and the view rotates slowly right a few degrees to track the ship. It's during this slight bit of rotation that some of the stars in the cluster look a bit funny to me, as though they comprise an object in the relative foreground.

Comment: Lots of starfields have easter eggs in them, for example: https://www.flickr.com/photos/38908546@N00/1764885977/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably just a coincidence.

- I wasn't able to find any reference to this being by design
- TOS remastering was done under VERY VERY compressed [schedule](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series#Remastered):

  > The first few episodes were rushed, as CBS only gave its team "one month to deliver the first two episodes with over 120 new effects shots."
- The proportions are all wrong (the stars that look like nacelles were way too far away from the axis compared to Enterprise itself).

  It DOES look roughly similar if you try to match the pattern hard enough (see below), but is not really unambiguous - JustJeff's perception ended up 180 degrees off from mine, literally (compare sketch in my answer to the one he later added to his question):

[image]

Comment: Well, the fact that we both saw it in different orientation likely means it wasn't designed as an easter egg :)  Plus, nacelle distance is still too wide.

Comment: Yea, it just seems like a big blob of nothing to me. I think this can be attributed to the psychological phenomenon called [Pareidolia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia). It's a quirk of human perception that causes us to see faces or other pictures/patterns in random noise (burnt toast, stucco walls, popcorn ceilings, tortilla chips, etc.). For me, usually after I "recognize" an image in a random pattern, I'll continue to see it again and again, with each viewing reinforcing that image in my mind. So to JustJeff the pattern probably seems quite obvious at this point.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté - actually, I still think it's a bit iffy, in this case, but of course I have no objective way to evaluate how much I might have succumbed.

Comment: @JustJeff: Ah, I assumed this was something that jumped out at you every time you watched the intro. It sounds like the effect isn't too pronounced in this case.

Comment: "I think this can be attributed to the psychological phenomenon called Pareidolia. It's a quirk of human perception". Yes, we do it constantly as a subconscious way of identifying patterns. In the same way you will dwell on items of interest subconsciously - try it for yourself. Consider buying a new car, a white Fiat 500 Abarth. Look at some pictures of the car, read up about it. You will suddenly start seeing them all around you through the day. Its not magic, they were there all the time. Your brain is now looking for the pattern so you now see them consciously.

Comment: And advertisers use this as a form of light brain washing. Listen closely next time and consider how they accentuate words in the script and repeat key phrases 6 or 7 times during the 60 second TV broadcast. You don't notice but your brain does and you start to recognise and associate the brand with the product - e.g. Hoover. Its a brand not a device. Search sublimal advertising - you may be shocked.

Answer (score 1):

One of the planets that is rotating has a map of New Zealand on it.

**UPDATE WITH DETAILS:**

This may not actually be the case. From the comments on [this website](http://www.eeggs.com/items/49501.html):

> I think the submitter is stretching this. The only planets shown during the introduction are Earth, Saturn, and Jupiter. There are no lava planets. If the submitter is talking about the image of Jupiter (a gas giant), the part that loosely resembles New Zealand is the giant red spot, a storm that has been raging on the surface of Jupiter for a very long time. No planets outside our own solar system are shown.

Comment: Earth, Saturn, and Jupiter appear in the opening credits of Star Trek: The Next Generation. The question is about the opening credits of the remastered original series (the 1966-1969 episodes with modern special effects).

Comment: This answer refers to The Next Generation. Different seasons, different opening credits. The lava planet with the map of NZ is not Jupiter, which was in earlier seasons. Besides, the question is about The Original Series.

Comment: Oh yes, so it is!